# Slower query in PDO Sqlite than command line Sqlite3 Client

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a table with 1.5M rows, which includes a integer column.

I want to get the SUM of integer column:

```
SELECT SUM(integer_column) FROM mytable;
```

In Sqlite3 command line client execution time is less than 1 seconds.

But in PHP PDO Sqlite, it take about 20 seconds:

```
$connection = new PDO('sqlite:/PATH/my.db');
$sql = "SELECT SUM(integer_column) FROM mytable";
$statement = $connection->query($sql);
$result = $statement->fetchColumn();
```

Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Are you measuring just the time to do the select in php, or the time to open the database **and** the select?

Comment: @Shawn I donot know any way, how to measure the time to open database and query time. 

"Explain Query Plan" show that, it uses proper indexes.

Comment: How much time does it take between You type they command `sqlite3 ./PATH/my.db` and the clinet open up and responsive to your command?